# check if class exists within file without requiring/including

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if class exists within a file without including/requiring the class?

Something like: `class_in_file($file);`

As I already mentioned, I know this can be done with requiring/including the class and then looking up `class_exists($class);`, but any other ways?

Comment: Well no....as it stills requires the file to check if the class exists in that file....otherwise how else would it know? if you had a class_in_file it would still need to read the file.

Comment: It would help people a lot if you explain why you think you need this.

Comment: @Jamie I think he means `include` and `require`, which are different from just reading the file.

Comment: I need this for dynamic navigation built from PHP files. And only if the file contains specific class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's no explanation. If you use [`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), the appropriate class will be loaded when needed. Please show some code where you need this. Reading PHP files to see if there's a class in that file seems very weird to me.

Comment: And that's the problem, I don't need to autoload it, I just want to lookup if class exists within specific file.

Comment: And my question is, again, **why** one would need that. Do you have a `menu` directory, from where you'll read all PHP files and include them if they contain `class MenuItem` or something like that? And there isn't another solution? But I see you've accepted an answer, so good luck. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents('foo.php'));
```

Then go through the tokens to see if you can spot a certain `T_CLASS` entry.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: I missed those functions, they are great. Thanks for that info

Comment: performance wise, what would be the difference with including/requiring the file? I think both methods have to load the entire file.

Comment: @Dann Performance wise including the file would be a lot faster. But the OP apparently doesn't want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

A php file is a text file, you can open it and parse it in order to find a 
class declaration.

It isn't a simple process, but a good parser should make the task trivial.

You have to strike out commented lines, strings containing a class declaration can trigger a false-positive, heredocs tend to make things more complex. Evals should be taken in account also.

if you have access to a command line php interpreter, then you can have a look at -w switch that strips comments and whitespaces for you doing a good half of yor work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  There are only workarounds.  For example, you could parse the file yourself (perhaps using `token_get_all`), or perhaps mark the file somehow with a comment at the top like

```
<?php
/** #has_class(CLASSNAME)
 */
```

and read the first few lines looking for this with a `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will only know which classes exist if it has loaded (parsed) the files they're defined in (assuming they're not built in). If you have a clearly defined structure (maybe you're using autoloading), you could possibly check that a class exists simply by checking that the file that defines it exists. e.g. `if (file_exists('<path to app>/lib/Myapp/Util/Http.php'))` could be used as a check that the `Myapp_Util_Http` class exists in your app directories. It's no guarantee the class *does* actually exist in that file though. For that you either have to include/require it, read it and parse it, or use autoloading and try using it.